# Переменные в JS

Tags: javascript, переменные

Только-только начал изучать джаваскрипт, и появился вопрос.
Мне нужно получить имя пользователя из input'a на одной странице, и потом это имя использовать на других страницах.
Но я не понимаю как это сделать...
Буду очень рад помощи!

Answer (score 0):

Используйте для этих целей куки
https://learn.javascript.ru/cookie

либо локал сторэдж
https://itchief.ru/lessons/javascript/javascript-sessionstorage-and-localstorage